# Do cloves in an apple repel fruit flies

Tags: natural-remedies, entomology

Some cloves in apples have recently appeared in our office. Apparently they will repel fruit flies. They look exactly like the result of following [these instructions](http://www.wikihow.com/Get-Rid-of-House-Flies-with-Cloves).

[image]

Is there any evidence to suggest that this would really repel fruit flies?

Comment: FYI the referenced link says "house flies" not "fruit flies".

Comment: Correct, the link does say that. However, I was told that the apples were to repel fruit flies in this particular instance.

Comment: I'm trying to bring this back, even though the links I have seen shared are about lemons and mention both house flies and mosquitoes.

Comment: There are many studies that show an effect of extracts and essential oils from cloves as an insect deterrant, affecting fruit flies, house flies, and mosquitoes, yet I couldn't find a study on the effect of just the cloves. I don't think that a post based on this would really answer whether there is "any evidence to suggest that [a clove-studded apple] would really repel fruit flies", would it?